# Vim: How to use function call results in : prompt commands

Tags: vim

As an example, suppose I have a few windows open in vim:

```
:echo winnr()
:argument 5
```

... will print out the current window number, then switch to the 5th file passed to vim on the command-line.  Supposing `winnr() == 5`, then I would expect ...

```
:argument winnr()
```

... to open the 5th file for editing.  However, vim treats this as though I had typed `argument` with no parameters.

can I use function call results as parameters to vim commands as attempted above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer.  I thought about deleting the question, but someone might like to know the answer.

```
:execute 'argument ' . winnr()
```